# Documentar o swagger utilizando anotações xml em .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, documentação, swagger

Eu estou tentando documentar minha API do swagger com comentários XML no meu código ele está assim

```
/// <summary>
/// Código
/// </summary>
/// <example>1</example>
public int? Code { get; set; }
/// <summary>
/// Recurso
/// </summary
public CodeNameParams Feature { get; set; }
```

Eu ja configurei corretamente todos os arquivos para conseguir adicionar estes tipos de comentários ao swagger e até fiz um teste utilizando o atributo Code e sim la funciona aparece tudo certinho. Porém com o atributo Feature nao aparece o meu summary eu acho que é porque o meu atributo Feature nao tem um tipo basico e sim uma classe que eu mesmo criei.

Eu olhei o json do meu swagger e ele esta assim

```
 "Customer3Params": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "code": {
        "type": "integer",
        "description": "Código",
        "format": "int32",
        "nullable": true,
        "example": 1
      },
      "feature": {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CodeNameParams"
      },
```

Como faria para documentar corretamente este meu atributo?

Answer (score 0):

Atualizando: Enfrentei o desafio de documentar uma estrutura complexa de parâmetros em minha aplicação, muitos dos quais não são tipos primitivos. Depois de pesquisar e experimentar várias abordagens, encontrei uma solução que superou minhas expectativas: o uso de Schema Filters no Swagger.

Segue um passo a passo de como implementei os Schema Filters:

1. Criei uma classe em C#, como por exemplo, "XptoParamsSchemaFilter".
2. Essa classe implementa a interface ISchemaFilter do Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.
3. A interface possui o método Apply, responsável por aplicar as modificações nos esquemas.
4. Adicionei meu filtro personalizado na configuração do Swagger, dentro do método AddSwaggerGen em Program.cs.

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(opt =>
{
    opt.SchemaFilter<XptoParamsSchemaFilter>();
});
```

1. No método Apply da classe XptoParamsSchemaFilter, fiz as personalizações necessárias. Por exemplo:

```
public void Apply(OpenApiSchema model, SchemaFilterContext context)
{
    if (context.Type == typeof(XptoParams)) // A partir deste if eu pego o tipo que eu quero alterar e documentar na minha context
    {
        model.Type = "object"; // define como será mostrado o tipo do seu objeto no schema
        model.Title = "Xpto"; // define o título do seu schema
        model.Required = new HashSet<string> {"code"}; // define quais campos no seu schema serão mostrados como required
        model.Properties = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiSchema> // definirá as propriedades do seu schema
        {
            {
                "code", new OpenApiSchema
                {
                    Type = "int", Description = "Código", Example = new OpenApiInteger(1)
                }
            },
            {
                "feature", new OpenApiSchema // Exemplo de um tipo mais "complexo"
                {
                    Type = "object", Description = "Recurso", Title = "CodeNameParams",
                    Properties = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiSchema>
                    {
                        { "code", new OpenApiSchema { Type = "integer", Description = "Código do status", Example = new OpenApiInteger(1) } },
                        { "name", new OpenApiSchema { Type = "string", Description = "Nome do status", Example = new OpenApiString("string") } },
                    }
                }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

1. Com essas alterações, a documentação do Swagger reflete diretamente as modificações feitas nos modelos de dados, proporcionando uma documentação minuciosa e completa.
   Essa abordagem me permitiu documentar detalhadamente minha API no Swagger, mantendo a limpeza e a clareza do código, sem a necessidade de lidar diretamente com códigos XML. Espero que esta explicação seja útil!